# Howto: count between velocity macro's using value from the request

Tags: velocity

i need to count how often a velocity macro is called.

something like:

```
#macro( doSometing )

  #set($counter= $counter + 1)
  i'm used ${counter} times.
#end
```

i tried to create the var in the jsp first with this:

```
<c:set var="counter" scope="request">1</c:set>
```

but then it will always be 2

ps
after adding this first:
     #set ($counter = $Integer.parseInt($counter))

Answer (score 0):

```
#macro( doSometing )

    #if(!$counter)
         #set($counter= 0)
    #end

    #set($counter= $counter + 1)
    i used ${counter} times.
#end
```

This can depend on velocity config but generally velocity variables are global and exist for the duration for the request